# Re-animating simulation after removing nodes in d3.js version 4 api force layout

Tags: force-layout, d3.js

I am grouping nodes together and laying them out evenly around the circumference of a circle. I would then like to be able to remove a group of nodes, recalculate the positions of the nodes on the circle and animate them to their new positions using d3.js version 4 of the force simulation. I have this partially working but i can't seem to figure out why when i remove the nodes and recalculate the new co-ordinates they do not move to their new positions. I am hoping someone can help. I'm new to d3.js so it's probably something fairly fundamental but as this is the latest version of the api and the force layout has changed quite a bit there's not a lot of examples (that i can find) out there in the wild.

I have linked to a jsbin of the partially working example below

https://jsbin.com/yetifunoso/4/edit?html,js,output